# monitor and conditional variable, are they the same?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, mutex, monitor

I'm much confused by this description of monitor on Wiki, which says:

> A monitor consists of a mutex (lock) object and condition variables.
>   A condition variable is basically a container of threads that are
>   waiting on a certain condition. Monitors provide a mechanism for
>   threads to temporarily give up exclusive access in order to wait for
>   some condition to be met, before regaining exclusive access and
>   resuming their task.

My question is: this seems exactly what `cond.wait(locker, [](){return !q.empty();});` does in C++. Why this is called monitor? Are they the same? Thanks!

```
mutex mu;
condition_variable cond;
...        
unique_lock<mutex> locker(mu);
cond.wait(locker, [](){return !q.empty();});
```

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, a *monitor* is an object that has a *condition variable* associated with it (and a *mutex*, as the condition variable depends on that), allowing threads to either *wait* on the condition variable or *notify* another thread through the condition variable.

In Java, every `Object` is a monitor. In C++, you have to set it up yourself by defining a `mutex` and `condition_variable`, and explicitly locking the `mutex` (with `unique_lock`) before you call `wait()`.

In other words, *monitor* is a concept, while *condition variable* is an implementation detail.